# Apache Ignite map-reduce way of solving equations

Tags: java, mapreduce, ignite

I have an equation that can be described by a tree. So the leaves are values with parent vertex being a math operator and when the computation is done, another value appears in the place of parent vertex and it becomes a leaf with a parent vertex(as math operator). The tree is not balanced and can have uneven depth depending on which branch you are pursuing.

What I need to know is how to use Apache ignite (I chose it because of its  event propagation mechanism that suits my needs) in order to parallelize by sending all the leaves at different depths(along with their parent vertices) for computation and so on until the equation is calculated.

Am I using wrong technology for this?

Is this problem not suited for map-reduce technologies?

What would be the best technology, which also has event propagation technology built in?

I'm just 1 point short of putting a bounty...

EDIT: Added bounty. Essentially my requirement is computing variable sub problems in a distributed computing solution than similar ones being map-reduced. Any solutions exist? Any thoughts are appreciated.

Comment: Credible and/or Official sources means API.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's possible with Ignite. You need to implement `ComputeTaskAdapter`'s `map()` and `reduce()` methods. First method will map your tasks to nodes, and second collects computation results. Refer [example](https://github.com/apache/ignite/blob/master/examples/src/main/java/org/apache/ignite/examples/computegrid/ComputeTaskMapExample.java).

After that you may run it again if previous reduce returned collection of results.

To decrease amount of data transferring you may use cache, and store intermediate data in it. If you map tasks to nodes, that have required data, all entries will be available for that tasks locally, and there will not be need to query them from remote node. To map tasks in this manner you may use

`ClusterNode dataNode = ignite.affinity("cacheName").mapKeyToNode("key");`

Here `dataNode` is a primary node for this key, and if task will be started on it, the whole entry will be available locally.

Comment: Thanks a lot! i realize that is the way to go but problem is a bit trickier. The _dataNode_ that you showed helps but each time i send out map work, it will be in the form of `var1<operation>var2` where `var1` can be on one node and `var2` on another node. I need reduce work only if the results are from leaves of same level. So i need to store results external to map/reduce methods to repeatedly process and join the results. I can do that in the static class but can i run the map/reduce repeatedly, kinda like in a loop until all levels of the equation tree are done?

Comment: i marked your answer as correct. it will automatically give bounty tomorrow. Any chance you can answer rest of my question?

Comment: I think you need to split your task tree on subtrees, where each subtree will be bound to single node, so you will be able to parallelize whole task on cluster. I suppose following usage. Client maps to nodes tasks that repeatedly do map-reduce only locally. When each subtree done it results to master node, which does final processing. Thanks! :)